# Update point by changing coordinates in attributes table [QGIS]

Tags: qgis

I have a csv file with a bunch of points and its UTM coordinates (around 120 features). The points are planned drillholes for a diamond drilling campaign, but the planned ones differ from the final ones measured on the field with a diferential GPS.

I loaded the planned points into QGIS, but eventually I will need to update those points via the attribute table and I need that the new coordinate moves in the map also (just like you do it in Google Earth).

Is there a way to do that without having to reload the updated csv table every time? Maybe using some sort of database or another format that updates automatically as I change the values os X and Y?

Comment: It is not possible to change CSV files within QGIS, if you edit the coordinates outside of QGIS with a text editor for example, the new positions will be updated in QGIS

Comment: @eurojam It is possible to edit a CSV within QGIS, you just need to use the "add vector layer" way rather than the "add delimited text way" (you will need to set the parameter manually if the default are not right for you) unfortunately editing the X and Y column doesn't seem to work if specified as geometry column… It's still possible to add an editable CSV as a table and use a virtual layer for displaying the point

Comment: @J.R. thanks, I didn't know that!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's not possible to update geometries by changing field values, I mean, it's possible but you'll need to run a process or import data again.
What you can do is to use the geometry generator to display the points according to field values, this will change just the symbology but not the geometry. So if you just want to display the points according to the coordinates from the x and y fields this will work, if you want to do processing it will take the old coordinates and wont work.

**Using the geometry generator**: Go to symbology and set the parameters as shown down bellow, replace in the expression `make_point("x", "y")` the field names with your coordinates.
[image: 1]